# gcc is not recognized as a command in the vscode terminal

Tags: c

When I try to run some very basic code(literally 5 lines) I get the error: "'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." mingw is installed and added to path and when I type gcc --version in cmd everything is fine. I'm using the VSCode editor and I'm running Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to restart VSCode. I know that if you add/remove anything from PATH and VSCode was already running, you need to re-launch it for any PATH changes to work.

Comment: The reason is that a running application had already received its environment. Any later change will only affect applications started there after.